# setState not getting called after useQuery call in submit?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I have a form where upon submit i call a usequery call to post the data and change one the sate variable but anything after the hook call is not being called.

```
        initialValues: {
            containerType: '',
            labelCode: '',
            useCode: ''
        },
        validationSchema: Validation_Control_ContainerMangement,
        onSubmit: async (values, actions) => {
            console.log(values.labelCode,)
            const serialLabel = values.labelCode != '' && (labelCodeList.filter((item) => item.id == values.labelCode))[0].name;
            const serialUse = (useCodeList.filter((item) => item.id == values.useCode))[0].name;
            const serialNumber = generateSerialNumber({ serialLabel, serialUse, serialNumberList });
            const addNewContainerPayload = generatePayloadNewConatiner(values.containerType, values.labelCode, values.useCode, serialNumber);

           

            const {
                data: addNewContainerInstance,
                //@ts-ignore
            } = useQuery('add-new-container', AccessionApi.addNewContainerInstance(addNewContainerPayload));

            setGeneratedSerialNumber(serialNumber);
            console.log(addNewContainerInstance);

        }
    });
```

Let me know if there's anything i am doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: Hooks like useQuery () must be the first statements in your function component. You have called it in your handler function. Can you please post the whole component code?

Comment: hooks should be used in the top level inside functional components. you cannot just slap on a `//@ts-ignore` and expect it to work. it's throwing an error because there is an issue.